# How can I change free_pages_high and free_pages_low in kernel 2.6.3x (ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: memory-management, kernel, swap

Does anyone know how I can change the kswapd min_pages and high_pages for linux kernel on ubuntu boxes?

The min_pages can be changed on /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes, but I cannot find how other parameters can be changed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, using /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes all values can be set automatically. http://mariosmarduch.ulitzer.com/node/431838/mobile